# TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000]. with \label command in macro

Tags: errors, cross-referencing

i try to write a macro which must put one or two label depending of the input parameter: 
input=⟨`test1`⟩ must write one label: `\label{sec:test1}`

input=⟨`test1,test2`⟩ must write two labels: `\label{sec:test1}\label{test2}`

For one label it's OK but for two the compilation return:

```
TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000]. 
...bsection{Test}\ecriturelabel{test1,test2}
```

The macro is write as follow:

```
\usepackage{xifthen}

\usepackage{xstring}

\newcommand{\ecriturelabel}[1]{

\ifthenelse{\isin{,}{#1}}{\def\labelone{sec:\StrBefore{#1}{,}}}{\def\labelone{sec:#1}}
\ifthenelse{\isin{,}{#1}}{\def\labeltwo{sec:\StrBehind{#1}{,}}}{\def\labeltwo{}}
\ifthenelse{\isin{,}{#1}}{\label{\labelone}\label{\labeltwo}}{\label{\labelone}}
}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: This might be a circular reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_reference

Comment: According to the text in your question you wish the second label to be `test2` while according to the code-snippet in your question you want it to be preceded by `sec:`, i.e., `sec:test2`. Please clarify!

Comment: @CampanIgnis No circular reference. Just two `\label`s are placed. Thus the same referencing-data will be available for cross-referencing under two names. The problem is: The macros of the `xstring` package are not expandable. Therefore they cannot be placed into the argument of the `\label`-command.

Comment: Be aware that when writing questions, in normal text, i.e., outside code-snippets, you cannot use "<" and ">" directly as these characters will be taken for something that introduces/ends a html-tag. If the html-tag is unknown, "<" and ">" and everything in between will just not be displayed. Instead use, e.g., the html-entities `&langle;` (yields: ⟨) and `&rangle;` (yields: ⟩)  or `&lt;`(yields: <) and `&gt;`(yields: >).

Comment: @UlrichDiez Thank you.

Comment: The definition text of `\ecriturelabel` begins with an empty line. That empty line will be taken for a token `\par`. Is this intended? Please clarify.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see, you'd like to do

```
\ecriturelabel{a,b}
```

so that this issues `\label{sec:a}` and `\label{b}`, but `\ecriturelabel{a}` only does `\label{sec:a}`.

There's no way that `\def\labelone{sec:\StrBefore{#1}{,}}` can work, because `\label` needs a fully expandable argument.

You can do it much more easily:

```latex
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\ecriturelabel}[1]{%
  \def\el@perhaps{sec:}%
  \@for\next:=#1\do{\label{\el@perhaps\next}\def\el@perhaps{}}%
}
\makeatother
```

which will work for any number of comma separated items in the argument to `\ecriturelabel`.

Full example:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\ecriturelabel}[1]{%
  \def\el@perhaps{sec:}%
  \@for\next:=#1\do{\label{\el@perhaps\next}\def\el@perhaps{}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{a}\ecriturelabel{a}

\section{bc}\ecriturelabel{b,c}

\end{document}
```

Here's the contents of the `.aux` file.

```latex
\relax 
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1}a}{1}\protected@file@percent }
\newlabel{sec:a}{{1}{1}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {section}{\numberline {2}bc}{1}\protected@file@percent }
\newlabel{sec:b}{{2}{1}}
\newlabel{c}{{2}{1}}
```

A more flexible solution using `xparse` and `expl3`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\ecriturelabel}{O{sec}m}
 {
  \poulot_labels:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }

\seq_new:N \l_poulot_labels_seq
\tl_new:N \l_poulot_label_first_tl

\cs_new_protected:Nn \poulot_labels:nn
 {
  \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l_poulot_labels_seq { #2 }
  \seq_pop_left:NN \l_poulot_labels_seq \l_poulot_label_first_tl
  \label{#1:\l_poulot_label_first_tl}
  \seq_map_function:NN \l_poulot_labels_seq \label
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\section{a}\ecriturelabel{a}

\section{bc}\ecriturelabel{b,c}

\begin{theorem}\ecriturelabel[theorem]{d,e}
Statement
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

The `.aux` file:

```latex
\relax 
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1}a}{1}\protected@file@percent }
\newlabel{sec:a}{{1}{1}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {section}{\numberline {2}bc}{1}\protected@file@percent }
\newlabel{sec:b}{{2}{1}}
\newlabel{c}{{2}{1}}
\newlabel{theorem:d}{{1}{1}}
\newlabel{e}{{1}{1}}
```

The command has an optional argument for the prefix to be added to the first label.

The idea is to form a sequence of items from the given argument; the first item is detached and the label with the prefix is generated; the remaining items are passed to `\label` one by one.

Answer (score 1):

Quote from the manual of the xstring package:

> 3.2 Expansion of macros, optional argument
>
> The macros of this package are not purely expandable, i.e. they cannot be put in the argument of an `\edef`. Nestling macros is not possible neither.
>
> For this reason, all the macros returning a result (i.e. all excepted the tests) have an optional argument in last position.
>   The syntax is `[⟨name⟩]`, where `[⟨name⟩]` is the name of the control sequence that will receive the result of the macro:
>   the assignment is made with an `\edef` which make the result of the macro `[⟨name⟩]` purely expandable. Of course, if an
>   optional argument is present, the macro does not display anything.
>
> Thus, this structure not allowed, supposed to assign to `\Result` the 4 chars on the left of `xstring`:
>   `\edef\Result{\StrLeft{xstring}{4}}`
>   is equivalent to :
>   `\StrLeft{xstring}{4}[\Result]`
>
> And this nested structure, not allowed neither, supposed to remove the first and last char of `xstring`:
>   \StrGobbleLeft{\StrGobbleRight{xstring}{1}}{1}
>   should be written like this:
>   `\StrGobbleRight{xstring}{1}[\mystring]`
>   `\StrGobbleleft{\mystring}{1}`

Being not purely expandable does not only mean that things cannot be put in "the argument" of an `\edef`. It also means that things can generally not be used in full expansion contexts which means that they also cannot be put in the argument of a `\label`-command.

Perhaps the following approach is helpful:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xifthen}
\usepackage{xstring}

\newcommand{\ecriturelabel}[1]{%
  \ifthenelse{\isin{,}{#1}}{%
    \StrBefore{#1}{,}[\labelname]%
    \label{sec:\labelname}%
    \StrBehind{#1}{,}[\labelname]%
    \label{\labelname}%
  }{%
    \label{sec:#1}%
  }%
}%

\begin{document}

\section{Test}

\subsection{Test}

\ecriturelabel{test1,test2}

\noindent\ref{sec:test1}

\noindent\ref{test2}

\end{document}
```

The code above does neither take into account the case of more than one comma nor take into account the case of spaces surrounding elements of the comma-list of labels nor take into account cases like `\ecriturelabel{,}`, `\ecriturelabel{test1,}`, `\ecriturelabel{,test2}` etc.